# Using Provider in Parent and Child cause Null check operator used on a null value Error

Tags: flutter

I get the following error when I use a Provider in my ProductsScreen.dart.

```
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  ProductsScreen
```

My ProductsScreen contains another Widget called ProductsList which uses another Provider.

The error only occurs when I am use Provider in both my parent 'ProductsScreen' and child 'ProductsList'.

When I am using Provider in my other screens that don't contain children that uses Provider, it works fine

May I know what is the reason for such an error? What should I do to use 2 Providers - one in the parent and one in the child widget? or is that not possible? Thanks

Below are snippets of my code...

ProductsScreen

```
class _ProductsScreenState extends State<ProductsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;

    return Stack(
      children: const [
        // Text(user.email),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        ProductsList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ProductsList

```
class ProductsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    print(productsData);
    final products = productsData.items;

    return Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: products.length,
        // 198 Nested Models & Providers
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: products[index], child: const ProductItem()),
        //value: products[index], child: ProductItem(id: products[index].id)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UserProvider

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

About (Working Fine)

```
class About extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/about';

  const About({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(user.email),
        const Text('Yup'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Products Provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Product> _items = [
    Product(id: '1', price: 10, isFavorite: false),
    Product(id: '2', price: 20, isFavorite: false),
    Product(id: '3', price: 50, isFavorite: true)
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  void addProduct() {
    // _items.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Main.dart (Snippet)

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // print(kIsWeb); // Need flutter/foundation package
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => UserProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Products(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData.dark()
            .copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor),
        // theme: ThemeData(
        //   // This is the theme of your application.
        //   //
        //   // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        //   // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        //   // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        //   // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        //   // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        //   // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        //   // is not restarted.
        //   primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        // ),
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const TabsScreen();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                }
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              return const LoginScreen();
            }),

        // initialRoute: LoginScreen.routeName,
        routes: {
          // '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Cool App'),
          // '/': (context) => const TabsScreen(),
          TabsScreen.routeName: (context) => const TabsScreen(),
          SignupScreen.routeName: (context) => const SignupScreen(),
          LoginScreen.routeName: ((context) => const LoginScreen()),
          About.routeName: ((context) => const About()),
          Demo.routeName: (context) => const Demo(),
          Settings.routeName: (context) => const Settings(),
          ProductsScreen.routeName: (context) => const ProductsScreen(),
          ProductDetail.routeName: (context) => const ProductDetail(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

UPDATE

*Interestingly, providers work fine in other screens except ProductsScreen. Following is a working example in AboutScreen. In AboutScreen, it calls UserProvider and the child widget ProductsList calls the ProductsProvider and they are working fine.

Only in the case of ProductsScreen which is the first screen that displays when user logs in that the UserProvider will throw a error when called

I have replaced my main.dart code to the full code in case anyone wanna tackle this issue. I'm starting to suspect its because TabsScreen which has ProductsScreen as first page has not loaded completely yet when the userProvider is called. I'm working based on that logic to troubleshoot*

```
class About extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/about';

  const About({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(user.email),
        const Text('Yup'),
        const Expanded(
          child: ProductsList(),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of these lines :

```
final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
print(productsData);
final products = productsData.items;
```

Do Products have items ?? Or you need to call some function to fill the items list with data

Comment: My Products Provider is very simple one. I have added the codes snippets above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the method `getUser` returns `null`, then this line will originate that error because you are using Null check operator `!` on Null value:

```
// class UserProvider
User get getUser => _user!;
```

You must be sure `null` never happens or you could change this to:

```
User? get getUser => _user;
```

And update:

```
// class About
model.User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
```

Comment: I understand. Interestingly, the code works fine as it currently is in my About Page. The error only appears when I use Provider in my ProductsScreen page which contains a child widget that contains a ProductsList that also uses a Provider. That's what befuddles me lol

Comment: I would prefer to have the null check to make sure null never happens. it seems the current Null check operator approach above works fine for other pages except the first page that loads. I was wondering if I could get Provider to work for that first page too?

Comment: The problem is Null is happening, so you have the error. You must make sure your code awaits for a User instance.

Comment: I agree Paulo. Thanks a lot. its the way the code is architectured. I will read around to see if other way to set up the user provider with firebase auth and if i come across anything good architecture, i will post it here for everyone's learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MultiProvider and wrap the stack in ProductsScreen with it

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [..],
      child: Stack());
```

Comment: I have d child in my MultiProvider. the code above is just part of the full code so as not to make my post too lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your _ProductScreenState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    final user = context.read<User>();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      await user.refreshUser();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: hi. adding your code triggers refreshUser to run again in my _ProductsScreenState and does not throw any error but how can I access and use email in the User class in my ProductsScreen? Sorry, im new to flutter and dart. Thanks

Comment: If you want to access email just write **context.read<User>().getUser.email** or if you want to make your widget rebuild when email changes just user context.watch instead of context.read